# Generic currency symbol returned by NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, iphone

For one (and only one…so far) of our beta testers, wherever our app tries to display a dollar sign, he instead sees the generic currency symbol described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_%28typography%29). I gather that this indicates that NSNumberFormatter can't determine the currency type for the current locale, yet he only sees this symbol in our app and his system region format is set to United States.

I'm simply using

```
[NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:value numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle]
```

Why would my app show the generic currency symbol instead of a $ ?

Comment: Can you get your hands on their device? The first thing I would do is take a very close look at the user's region settings

Comment: Sadly he's in another city. Verbally he tells me that in Settings > General > International he has Language set to English and Region Format set to United States. Is there another iOS setting that could affect this?